# how can I get rid of these dark area when tapping the button on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

the source code is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/hony-quekr

demo: https://quekr.csb.app/

The button itself is a `span` element. Here is the relevant code snippet.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import posed from "react-pose";
import "./Choice.css";

const config = {
  visible: {
    opacity: 1,
    y: 0,
    delay: 100
  },
  hidden: {
    opacity: 0,
    y: 8,
    delay: 200,
    transition: {
      duration: 200
    }
  }
};
const Underline = posed.div(config);

class Choice extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      isVisible: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ isVisible: this.props.visibility });
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props !== prevProps) {
      this.setState({ isVisible: this.props.visibility });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <span
        className="word"
        onMouseEnter={() => this.props.onMouseEnter()}
        onMouseLeave={() => this.props.onMouseLeave()}
        onClick={() => this.props.onClick()}
      >
        {this.props.name}
        <Underline
          className="underline"
          pose={this.state.isVisible ? "visible" : "hidden"}
        />
      </span>
    );
  }
}
```

The problem is with mobile devices, when viewing the page on mobile devices, there is a dark area appearing around every button when it is clicked(tapped) on. I have attached a picture to demonstrate.

[image]

I want to get rid of these dark areas so that nothing happens when you tap on these buttons except for the underlines showing up

Comment: Your demo works fine on my iPhone. No text selection on tap, as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this CSS:

```
.no-select {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none; 
  user-select: none;    
}
```